# Apps Script Error - "Execution failed: Login Required"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have the following line of code in my apps script file, followed by a basic **onOpen()** function to build a menu:

```
var listContainers = TagManager.Accounts.Containers.list('accounts/' + accountId);
```

When that line of code is commented out, the menu is created.  But if that line is not commented out, the menu is not created, and the script doesn't run.

When I check the execution transcript (*View --> Execution transcript*), I see the following error associated with the line shown above:

> Execution failed: Login Required

Under *Resources-->Advanced Google Services*, I have turned on the Tag Manager API, and I have also enabled that API in the Google API Console.  The **accountId** is one for a GTM account that I am the owner of.

This is what my manifest file looks like (*View --> Show manifest file*):

```js
{
  "timeZone": "America/Mexico_City",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tagmanager.delete.containers",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tagmanager.edit.containers",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tagmanager.edit.containerversions",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tagmanager.manage.users",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tagmanager.publish"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [{
      "userSymbol": "TagManager",
      "serviceId": "tagmanager",
      "version": "v2"
    }]
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "executionApi": {
    "access": "ANYONE"
  }
}
```

I feel like all of my grounds are covered here, so I'm not understanding why it is giving me that **Login Required** error.  I have googled up-and-down for a solution, and can't find anything indicating I am doing anything wrong.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated...thanks!

Comment: I see your manifest, but where is your code? If I understand your description of the code, you declare a global `listcontainers`, rather than call that from within a function? Why? globals are evaluated every single time Google runs any of your functions - wrap it in a function and call it. Plus, you can actually get more than 1 page of results that way.

Answer (score 1):

Global variables can't access external services that require authorization in the same way that simple triggers like onOpen and onEdit as well as custom functions can't access them.

If you really want that `listContainers` be a global variable You could initialize it at the global scope by doing something like

```
var listContainers;
```

Then on a function called by a user interface or an installable trigger assign the tag manager list to that variable in the following way:

```
listContainers = TagManager.Accounts.Containers.list('accounts/' + accountId);
```